# How to fix HTTPD (Apache) Error 256 on OSX Monterey 12.5

Tags: apache, homebrew, macos-monterey

I have a Apache2 installed with Homebrew on a Mac running OSX Monterey. I haven't done LAMP development for a while, so I'm not sure when the error started, but I've recently updated OSX to 12.5. When I returned to working on a LAMP project, my Apache installation stopped working. Running `brew services` produced the following output: `Name    Status     User   File httpd   error  256 root   ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist mysql   started    Nizz0k ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`.

Running the stop, start, and restart commands produces "success" output in the terminal, but Apache doesn't work. I can't navigate to my local vhosts, and of course, running `brew services` still shows an error.

In running `apachectl -e error` Apache complains about permissions to the error logs

I have tried:

1. uninstalling and reinstalling HTTPD
2. The apr-utilities fix.
3. confirming Mac installed Apache is stopped.

At this point, I think my problem is that there was conflicting information about how to run Apache on Homebrew. Earlier versions apparently required `sudo`, but running it this was now produces warnings like this:

```
Warning: Taking root:admin ownership of some httpd paths:
  /usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.54/bin
  /usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.54/bin/httpd
  /usr/local/opt/httpd
  /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin
  /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/httpd
This will require manual removal of these paths using `sudo rm` on
brew upgrade/reinstall/uninstall.
Warning: httpd must be run as non-root to start at user login!
/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist: service already bootstrapped
Bootstrap failed: 37: Operation already in progress
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` exited with 37.
```

The issue is even after removing the paths as suggested in the error, a reinstallation brings Root back as the owner.

Answer (score 4):

I do have the same problem with nginx.
Manually unloaded it and then restarting it worked fine.

Try:

```
sudo launchctl bootout system /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
sudo brew services start httpd
```

Comment: I'm not working on that system anymore, but I would have nuked the install because it was hopelessly borked. I've been moving to containers so I don't have to be dependent on local servers